# Setting specific labels options by expression in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, expression

I have a layer with all countries in the world but I need to label only six of them. I tried this expression:

```
 "NAME"  = 'Russia' AND 'Canada' AND 'China' AND 'USA' AND 'Brazil' AND 'Australia'
```

But as a result, I get a label only for Russia. Obviously, something is wrong. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use an AND your features have to fulfill *all your conditions at the same time* ... which is probably not what you expect ...

Try something like the following :

```
Name in ('Russia', 'Canada', 'China', 'USA', 'Brazil', 'Australia')
```

Use that expression in a **rule-based** labeling context *(Properties/Labels/Rule based labeling and use the previous expression as first rule)*

Comment: Thanks! It works even in single labeling!

Comment: The long hand would be "NAME"  = 'Russia' AND "Name" = 'Canada'...

Comment: @AWGIS your comment show the proper syntax for GeoEth wrong expression, the right way would use the OR operator not AND...

Comment: Apologies, yes you are correct!